# Replace sql database but keep old records

Tags: android, sql, upgrade

After a lot of work I managed to build my first app, but I stick with one question. For my app I am using a sql database.. Suppose I want to add 30 records to a certain table. How is it possible that when I put a new version in the android market with a new sql table to use this one for the future, but to keep the records of the previous database?

Does it has to do something with:

```
@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
```

EDIT

my databasehelper code:

```
 public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.test.com/databases/";
    private static String DB_NAME = "quizDb";
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    private final Context myContext;
    private Cursor c;
    static int numberOfLevels = 10;
    private final static int DB_VERSION = 2; // = until level 10


    /**
     * Constructor Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to
     * access to the application assets and resources.
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;

    }

    /**
     * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own
     * database.
     * */
    public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbExist) {
            // By calling this method and empty database will be created into
            // the default system path
            // of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that
            // database with our database.
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each
     * time you open the application.
     * 
     * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
     */
    private boolean checkDataBase() {
        File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        return dbFile.exists();
    }

    /**
     * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created
     * empty database in the system folder, from where it can be accessed and
     * handled. This is done by transfering bytestream.
     * */
    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {

        // Open your local db as the input stream
        InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

        // Path to the just created empty db
        String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        // transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        // Close the streams
        myOutput.flush();
        myOutput.close();
        myInput.close();

    }

    public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
        // Open the database
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close() {
        if (c != null)
            c.close();
        if (myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();

        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

    }

    public File getDatabasePath(String name) {

        File file = myContext.getDatabasePath(name);

        return file;
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE ? as AttachedDB",
                new String[] { getDatabasePath("quizDbNew").getPath() });
        db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO questions (_id, file, answer, level) SELECT _id, file, answer, level FROM AttachedDB.questions");
        db.execSQL("DETACH AttachedDB");

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The concept of using `"DROP TABLE"` in `onUpgrade()` is as primitive as database management gets, however more useful techniques require more SQL savvy. A smarter way to upgrade your databases by using [`"ALTER TABLE"`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html) to add new columns or otherwise finagle the old data into your new schema.

---

**Addition**
Below in the comments you stated (more or less):

> I want to copy the content from my backup file of Db v1 into my current Db v2

So let's set up a couple hypothetical tables:

- Database Version One (DBv1):

  ```
  CREATE TABLE Foo(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bar TEXT, bar2 TEXT, bar3 TEXT);
  ```
- Database Version Two (DBv2):

  ```
  CREATE TABLE Foo(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bar2 TEXT, bar4 INTEGER);
  ```

First let's see a regular upgrade from DBv1 to DBv2. SQLite only supports `ADD COLUMN` and `RENAME TO`, not `REMOVE COLUMN` or anythings else. So we have to re-create the entire table:

```
@Override  // DBv1 => DBv2
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE Foo RENAME TO OldFoo");
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE Foo(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bar2 TEXT, bar4 INTEGER)");
    db.execSQL("INSERT INTO Foo (_id, bar) SELECT _id, bar2 FROM OldFoo");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE OldFoo");
}
```

Again this created a table with DBv2's schema and kept all of the valid, existing data from DBv1 by inserting the appropriate columns into DBv2. (Then it removed the old data by dropping the old table.)

You have wisely chosen to backup your database over time in a separate file, but now you want to bring the old data into the new table schema. To start make sure that your backup SQLite file is in the same directory as your current SQLite file (`data/data/<reverse.package.name>/databases/`). It will obviously need a unique name, let's call it `DBBackup`. Now let's attach `DBBackup` to your current database and perform a similar action from above:

```
// DBBackupv1 => DBv2
public void restore(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE ? as AttachedDB", new String[] {getDatabasePath("DBBackup").getPath()});
    db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO Foo (_id, bar2) SELECT _id, bar2 FROM AttachedDB.Foo");
    db.execSQL("DETACH AttachedDB");
}
```

I used `INSERT OR IGNORE` to restore any rows that were deleted but left the current existing rows untouched. You can use `INSERT OR REPLACE` to revert to the backed up version. There are many more options to suit your needs.

Comment: +1 for a good answer, but mainly for getting "finagle" into a technical discussion.

Comment: I had an old boss that used [kerfuffle](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+kerfuffle) and [cattywampus](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+cattywampus) a lot, things were often broken there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I suppose there is no other way than this? Since I add the db file, it would be much faster to just copy the content of two tables of Db v1 to the new two tables in Db v2

Comment: "just copy the content of two tables of Db v1 to the new two tables in Db v2" It is possible to merge two similar tables from two different files too. The easiest way is to use a standard `DBHandler` for each database, then grab the appropriate columns from the old DB in a Cursor and insert them into the new DB.

Comment: Perfect! I'll look into that! I will use a combination of inserting new items to table 1 and to copy table 3 and 4 to the new Db! :)

Comment: @Sam, do you maybe have some kind of tutorial on this? I must say that I don't find anything which I can use as a basis. Since I am just starting programming android I must admit that I have a lack of knowledge about this issue... hope you can point me at some useful info which can take me further!

Comment: I also edited my original question and added my code to give you a view on how I build up my database..

Comment: Thanks @Sam, you have no idea how much I am looking forward to it :)

Comment: @MatthiasVanb I updated my answer with a way to merge a database from a backup file with your current database.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to fix it based on  your info and certainly get back to you to let you know how it turned out :) !

Comment: @Sam what do you mean by "Transfer your sqlite back into this directory, name it DBBackup". You mean just to add the db file to my assets folder and call it DBBackup? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Both the current and backup SQLite files need in the your app's `databases/` directory to use the code above. (I updated the answer, hopefully it's clearer.)

Comment: @Sam, I am really greatful but it doesn't seem to work for me... I keep having the regular database without the update, I don't get an error however.. I placed it under my onUpgrade method... I updated my answers to let you see what I made of it... The QuizDbNew is the new embedded Db file, QuizDb is the old one, in my assets folder. I am just breaking my head over it, damn!

Comment: By using [`INSERT OR IGNORE` SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html) will not touch any rows that exist in the current database, in other words if the current database has a row for every `_id` key in the backup database you won't see a change.

Comment: The QuizDbNew contains 40 new elements, from 31 to 70.. Is it right that I put it under the onUpgrade method?

Comment: Yes, you can use `onUpgrade()`. You only need access to `SQLiteDatabase db` and the version numbers help keep your code sorted. Have you double checked your backup SQLite file with [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) to make sure the extra data is there?

Comment: I see there only the original database (so the old one, with just 30 records... ) :s Should the new one be there as well?